# How can I use pickle in python 3 to create a save function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

My code is just a test so I can learn how pickle works. There's a list of words that the user can add an item to. I want to add the word to the list so that when the program is run again, the list will include the user's word. I don't understand how to do this, because you first have to define the list, so I end up with the original words plus the word the user wrote in that running of the program

```
    import pickle

    class info():
        words = ['skylight','revenue']

    item = input("Type a word: ")
    info.words.append(item)

    with open("savefile.pickle","wb") as handle:
        pickle.dump(info.words, handle)

    with open("savefile.pickle","rb") as handle:
        info.words = pickle.load(handle)

    print(info.words)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'll need a way to differentiate between first and second run. I'd recommend checking if the save file exists. If it does, you can load the pickle. Otherwise, you'll go with the "defaults."

What you have right now, is loading the pickle right after saving. It makes no sense.

You can use `os.path.isfile` to determine if the file exists.

```
import pickle
import os.path

class info():
    words = ['skylight','revenue']

if os.path.isfile("savefile.pickle"):
    with open("savefile.pickle","rb") as handle:
        info.words = pickle.load(handle)

item = input("Type a word: ")
info.words.append(item)

with open("savefile.pickle","wb") as handle:
    pickle.dump(info.words, handle)

print(info.words)
```